# Filter N number of columns for specific value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe with over 100 conditions as boolean columns (not an ideal setup but I can't change it). I'm trying to make a function that takes a variable number of condition-columns, then filters where all conditions are 1 or all are zero.

**SETUP**

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
ID <- sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE)
Val <- round(runif(length(ID), 20, 40),0)
cond_1 <- sample(0:1, length(ID), replace = TRUE)
cond_2 <- sample(0:1, length(ID), replace = TRUE)
cond_3 <- sample(0:1, length(ID), replace = TRUE)
cond_4 <- sample(0:1, length(ID), replace = TRUE)


df <- data.frame(ID, Val, cond_1, cond_2, cond_3, cond_4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Example of desired function for any two columns:**

```
filterTwoCols <- function(df, cols){

  # Select desired conditions
  df1 <- df %>% 
    select(ID, Val, one_of(cols))

  #### Filter on all conditions == 0 or all conditions == 1
  df2 <- df1 %>% 
    filter(.[,ncol(.)] == 1 & .[,ncol(.) - 1] == 1 |
           .[,ncol(.)] == 0 & .[,ncol(.) - 1] == 0)

  return(df2)
}

filterTwoCols(df, c('cond_1', 'cond_4'))
filterTwoCols(df, c('cond_3', 'cond_2'))
```

What I want to be able to do is to name any number of conditions (e.g. `filterManyCols(df, c('cond_1', 'cond_3', 'cond_4'))`, but I don't know how to do this without naming them explicitly in the filter (`.[,ncol(.) - 2] == 1`, `.[,ncol(.) - 3] == 1`, etc). If the number of columns selected don't match the number of conditions in the filter then it won't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `filter_at`

```
library(tidyverse)
filterManyCols <- function(df, cols){

 # Select desired conditions
 # Not clear whether we need to subset the columns or get the filtered 
 # full dataset columns
 # df <- df %>% 
 #       select(ID, Val, one_of(cols))

  map_df(0:1, ~ df %>%
                  filter_at(vars(one_of(cols)), all_vars(. == .x)))
 }

filterManyCols(df, c('cond_1', 'cond_4')) 
filterManyCols(df, c('cond_1', 'cond_2', 'cond_3'))   
filterManyCols(df, c('cond_1', 'cond_2', 'cond_3', 'cond_4'))
```